# How can i set the limited number of characters in uilabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I am developing one application.In that i have to set the limited number of characters for UIlabel.So please tell me how can i set that limited number of characters for UILabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for your desired length.
For example you want your uilabel limited upto 50 characters.

```
if([lbl.text length] > 50)
     nslog(@"stop");
else
     nslog(@"your stuff goes here");
```

Enjoy Programming!

Answer (score 1):

`UILabel` itself doesn't have a property to set the max length of the `text` property, so you can't do this using any properties or methods in the class itself.

You should check for the length of the string before you set it and decide there whether to allow it or not